# input from terminal <<<?

Tags: bash, shell

I saw the code written for testing our code with input from termial:

```
./spellcheck corpus_colors <<< rend
```

`corpus_colors` is the filename, I guess `rend` is for terminal input.

`<<<` behaves as terminal input?

Comment: "Terminal input" is a very specific thing; not all content on standard in is terminal input. For instance, for programs which read passwords direct from a terminal for security reasons, using `<<<` redirections (or any other kind of stdin redirection) will not work. This is why you can't use `<` or `<<<` to redirect passwords to sudo (with default/secure configuration) or ssh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<<<` is a bash extension (not available in baseline POSIX shells) which redirects literal content to stdin (with an added trailing newline). It is implementation-defined whether it appears to be a pipeline or a temporary file. It does not act as a terminal -- that is to say, `isatty()` will fail.

Compared to

```
echo rend | ./spellcheck corpus_colors
```

...using

```
./spellcheck corpus_colors <<<rend
```

can be slightly more efficient, avoiding the extra subshell needed to set up a pipeline. Avoiding this subshell also means that an operation can be a shell function which changes shell state, and these state changes can persist past the end of the function's execution.

See [the wikipedia article on "here strings"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Here_strings), or (better) [the relevant component of the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings).

Comment: @thatotherguy, ...information I was editing in as you typed. :)

Comment: Hi, but when I input this it says Missing name for redirect.why

Comment: @user3495562, because this is a bash-only feature, you can only use it in a bash shell. If your script starts with `#!/bin/sh`, or is started with `sh somescript`, here strings won't be available.

Comment: anyway echo works. it there three <<<? why in my computer(remotely log in stanford computer should work/...), but it does work for the case <<<

Comment: @user3495562, yes, it's three `<<<`s for herestrings. Check that you're using bash (started as bash, rather than in POSIX compatibility mode) if it doesn't work.

Comment: to make it work, what should I put in front of this command? I am a new to linux. Anyway

Comment: @user3495562, if you want to be sure something is run with bash, you can run it as follows: `bash -c './spellcheck corpus_colors <<<rend'`. I wouldn't put that in a script, however; instead, correctly set which shell the script is invoked with. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Choose_Your_Shell

Comment: thanks a lot, it takes some time for me to understand all these

Answer (score 2):

You can use certain characters to redirect both input and output.

Examples ...

```
./someprogram > foo.txt
```

Will replace the file `foo.txt` ( or create it ) and add the standard output of `someprogram`

```
./someprogram >> foo.txt
```

Will **append** the standard output of `someprogram` to the file `foo.txt` ( creating it if necessary )

```
./someprogram < foo.txt
```

Will use the contents of `foo.txt` as standard input for `someprogram`

```
./someprogram | someotherprogram
```

Will redirect the standard output of `someprogram` and use it as the standard input for `someotherprogram`

```
./someprogram < foo.txt > bar.txt
```

Will use the contents of `foo.txt` and the standard input of `someprogram` and redirect the standard output of `someprogram` to the file `bar.txt`

```
./someprogram <<< rends
```

Will use "rends\n" ( without the quotes ) as standard input for `someprogram`

[This page](http://www.westwind.com/reference/OS-X/commandline/pipes.html) has some good information on that topic.

Comment: Please include the important information from that page in your answer. Links might die which means your answer will be useless.

Comment: This contains a great deal of information irrelevant to understanding `<<<`, and (as presently edited) nothing but a link explicitly explaining it.

Comment: (-1 removed, now that this answer does in fact discuss `<<<`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy my original answer was to point OP in the right direction because I assumed it was a general question. I did a poor job of that and I shouldn't make that kind of assumption anyway. Thanks for removing the -1, though.

Answer (score 2):

Under BASH `<<<` is used to specify a 'Here String'.  It's an inline version of a 'Here Document'.  What ever comes after `<<<` is fed into stdin of the calling program.  It is similar to echoing through a pipe to a command.  More information can be found here:
http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17837.html

Comment: FYI -- the ABS frequently demonstrates poor practices, and is not responsively maintained (making it difficult to have such errors corrected). The wiki at wooledge.org is more actively maintained (by freenode.org #bash channel regulars), and has another article on the subject: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument